# How to deserialize XML with key value pairs with XMLMapper

Tags: java, xml, objectmapper

I have a very simple XML file but I can't seem to get it to deserialize back into a POJO.

The file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings>
    <property name="a"  value="1"/>
    <property name="b"  value="2"/>
    <property name="c"  value="3"/>
    [...]       
</Settings>
```

With a very simple method of

```
  public void convertXml() {

    try {
      final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
      final Configuration configuration = xmlMapper.readValue(rawXml.getFile(), Configuration.class);

      log.info("Configuration parsed {}", configuration);

    } catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

And a couple of classes of which I'd have thought it would have gone into

```
public class Configuration {    
  private Settings settings;
}


public class Settings {
  private List<Property> property;
}


public class Property {
  private String name;

  private String value;
}
```

However the Configuration object just has a null value for the Settings property.

Have I missed the obvious here?

Comment: Probably because of lower case `s` try changing like this `private Settings Settings` So then you might need to rename you class

Comment: I attempted that but no luck. I think I need a `private Map<String, String> property` to map the name/value pairs but unsure how to do that and get more than just the last value in the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of annotations was the answer in the end

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Settings")
public class Configuration {

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  private List<Property> property;
}
```

And this allowed me to drop the middle Settings class.